# Sorting each column in a file into a separate array

Tags: c++, arrays

So I have a file with six columns, the first being date, and the rest being different sorts of stock information. (i.e., open, close, volume traded, etc.) I'm trying to sort each column into an array. Here's my function to do so:

```
void load_file(istream& fin, string date[], double open[], double high[],
               double low[], double close[], int vol[], int& day)
{
    day = 0;
    while (day < MAX_TRADING_DAYS)
    {
        fin >> date[day] >> open[day] >> high[day]
            >> low[day] >> close[day] >> vol[day];
        day++;
    }
}
```

Here's how a typical line (262 total, corresponding to `max_trading_days`) from the file looks:

```
3-Mar-14    1206.75 1207.84 1192.14 1202.69 2108720
```

When I'm outputting analysis of the stock information into another file, I'm getting completely garbage values so I'm guessing the issue is with how the information is being seen into the arrays in the first place. What would be the best way to accomplish this?

When I do try to display one of the arrays, XCode displays several differnt

Also, the file originally has a title row at the very beginning with the title of each column. I deleted this to try to figure out if this code would work or not. How could I ignore that first row when taking in information from the file?

Thanks!

Edit: When I do try to display one of the arrays after calling the function, XCode displays several different issues that I'm unsure how to navigate.

```
_LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
bool __is_long() const _NOEXCEPT
    {return bool(__r_.first().__s.__size_ & __short_mask);}

_LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY size_type size() const _NOEXCEPT
    {return __is_long() ? __get_long_size() : __get_short_size();}
```

Next to each of these it says "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x7fff5fcbdd78)"

Comment: How exactly is your file delimited?

Comment: Here's what a typical line will look like:

3-Mar-14 1206.75 1207.84 1192.14 1202.69 2108720

There's 262 trading days total, so just 262 lines of that exact setup.

Comment: Comments do not support newlines, please edit your question with the relevant format.

Comment: Well, to ask the obvious -- can you output the values at the exact moment when you read them, to the console or another file? Can you, perhaps -- heaven forbid -- debug?

Comment: I suspect the arguments you are passing to `load_file` don't have sufficient space to hold the data.

Comment: There's around 250 lines of text in the file, and each array is set to size MAX_TRADING_DAYS, which is 262.

Comment: So you trying to the records 262 times even though thee are only 250 lines of text? I would fix that first even though I am not sure that explains the errors you are seeing.

Comment: Read these FAQs, and work with the debugger.  http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/input-output.html  check for stream errors.  Coding this way without incorporating any checks for input failures is a bad idea.  You also haven't provided a compilable example for anyone else to work with so responders could only guess as to what the problem is.

Comment: Have you tried using ifstream instead istream??

Comment: @rm820, If you are running the code in a new thread, I'm guessing that `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` probably represents something like a `segfault` in one of your threads, although I'm not sure of this. See my answer for an example of how to correctly call your function.

Answer (score 0):

You are modifying *copies* of your parameters.

In C++, parameters are passed by value.  This means that a copy of the content in the original variable is passed to the function.  So if you modify parameters, you are modifying a copy, not the original.

You can around this in two ways: 1) Pass by reference or 2) Pass by pointer.  The first method allows you to modify or access the original variable without making a copy.  The second method allows you to change the content of the original variable because you know its location.  Pointers are nasty, prefer references.

So the compiler may be complaining that you are writing to copies of the variables or the variables are passed as read-only variables.

**Edit 1: Simplification Suggestion**
You can simplify your function signature by making a structure or class to model a row in your text file.  Pass an instance, by reference, to your input function or pass a `std::vector` by reference to input more than one row.

Also, you should overload `operator>>` in your structure to simplify to input loop:

```
struct Data_Row  
{
  friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Data_Row& d);
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Data_Row& d)
{
  // read members of 'd' from 'input'
  return input;
}

//.. your input loop
Data_Row dr;
std::vector<Data_Row> container;
while (input_file >> dr)
{
  container.push_back(dr);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm constrained into using strictly arrays and file I/O for this project (it's for school) so I don't think I could pull this off. But thanks for your answer! Also, I was under the impression from class that arrays do not use pass by value, but are instead similar to pass by reference. Could you explain a little more how pass by reference specifically would help in this situation?

Comment: arrays do not pass by value so I doubt that is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a problem in your code, it is likely elsewhere (for example, in how you allocate memory). Here is a working example, using your code, which correctly reads input in the format you specify.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <limits>

#define MAX_TRADING_DAYS 262

using namespace std;

void load_file(istream& fin, string date[], double open[], double high[],
        double low[], double close[], int vol[], int& day)
{
    // Ignore the header row
    fin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');

    // Start reading
    day = 0;
    while (day < MAX_TRADING_DAYS)
    {
        fin >> date[day] >> open[day] >> high[day]
            >> low[day] >> close[day] >> vol[day];
        day++;
        if (fin.eof()) break;
    }

    // We will not detect EOF until an extra line has been read, so we compensate.
    day--;
}

// A small function verify that we read correctly.
void dump_file(string* date, double* open, double* high,
        double* low, double* close, int* vol, int& day) {
    for (int i = 0; i < day; i++)
        cout << date[i] << "\t" 
            << open[i] << "\t"
            << high[i] << "\t"
            << low[i] <<  "\t"
            << close[i] <<  "\t"
            << vol[i] << endl;
}


int main(){
    ifstream mystream("Trade.in", std::ifstream::in);

    string* date     = new string[MAX_TRADING_DAYS];
    double* open     = new double[MAX_TRADING_DAYS];
    double* high     = new double[MAX_TRADING_DAYS];
    double* low      = new double[MAX_TRADING_DAYS];
    double* close    = new double[MAX_TRADING_DAYS];
    int* vol         = new int[MAX_TRADING_DAYS];
    int day;

    load_file(mystream, date,open,high,low,close,vol,day); 
    dump_file(date,open,high,low,close,vol,day); 
}
```